# Retrieve Max value from a field using Spring Data and MongoDB

Tags: spring-data-mongodb

I want to obtain the maximum value of the field `code` within my `User` entity, using Spring Data and MongoDB.

I have seen similar examples using as below,

```
".find({}).sort({"updateTime" : -1}).limit(1)"
```

But have no idea how to integrate it into my own `repository` using the `@Query` annotation.

Any alternative solution, than to return the maximum value of said field is also welcome.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a custom method for your repository. 
For example you have:

```
public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User, String>, UserRepositoryCustom {
...
}
```

Additional methods for repository:

```
public interface UserRepositoryCustom {
    User maxUser();
}
```

And then implementation of it:

```
public class UserRepositoryImpl implements UserRepositoryCustom { 
    @Autowired
    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    @Override
    public User maxUser() {
        final Query query = new Query()
                .limit(1)
                .with(new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "updateTime"));

        return mongoTemplate.findOne(query, User.class)
    }
}
```

Comment: Query <-- 
Which package exactly is, I get 8 possible options. Thank you.

Comment: import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query;

Answer (score 3):

You can use the spring data method syntax like:
`public User findTopByOrderByUpdateTimeAsc()`

A reference can be found here: https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-limit-query-results#1first-ortop

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in spring to get the latest updated time from mongodb: (mongoTemplate)

```
public List getTopPosts() {
        Query query = new Query();
        query.with(Sort.by(Sort.Direction.DESC, "postUploadedTime"));
        return mongoTemplate.find(query,Post.class);
    }
```