# Spring Repository, create manual covered query for max value

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, repository, max

I'm trying to pull the max value for the startTime in a Mongo collection. I also anticipate that this table will grow pretty big and I'll need to make this query often, so I want to use a covered query (https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/core/query-optimization/#covered-query) by putting an index on the startTime.

This solution is close ([Max value from field Spring Data and Mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45305983/max-value-from-field-spring-data-and-mongodb)) but I think it will be too slow.

This is the query I'm trying to use:

```
db.collection.find({}, {startTime: 1, _id:0}).sort({startTime:-1}).limit(1)
```

But I'm struggling to figure out how to add it to the @Query annotation for Spring's Repository.

Edit:

Here is a solution, although I'm not sure how efficient it is or if it's actually a covered Mongo query. I need to find a better reference/doc

```
List<CandleEntity> findTopByOrderByStartTimeDesc();
```

Comment: See the API Javadocs for [@Query](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/repository/Query.html).  The annotation has attributes to specify the query filter, projection (fields) and the sort.

Comment: I've read over that. It's unclear to me. I wish this was documented better.

Comment: What is unclear? Please show the code you are trying. You can also search for some examples online.

Comment: Here are some examples: https://javatechonline.com/spring-boot-mongodb-query-examples/#Step4_Create_a_Repository_Interface

Comment: It's unclear to me how to write this query. It looks like you can write a limited manual query, or use the method naming conventions along with the annotation types (value,count,sort,etc.) but not together. I've looked at numerous examples. Others have tried to figure this out. Most of the answers suggest looping over results. I think using the Repository, it's not possible to use a covered query to pull a value from Mongo.

Comment: The query returns a List collection, with one element.

Comment: I've tried that as well.

Comment: You didnt use the _limit_.

Comment: I've been trying to figure out how to append the limit. That one is especially unclear. But regardless, shouldn't I be able to see something if I look at the first element in the returns? System.out.println("Test: " + candleRepository.findTopOrderByStartTime().get(0).getStartTime());

Answer (score 0):

> db.collection.find({}, {startTime: 1,
> _id:0}).sort({startTime:-1}).limit(1)

The Spring Data MongoDB query definition to be used with *MongoRepository* for the above is as follows:

```
@Query(fields="{ startTime: 1, id: 0 }" )
CandleEntity findTopByOrderByStartTimeDesc();
```

You can also use this method signature: `findFirstByOrderByStartTimeDesc()`. Note the `@Query` should not have any other options (other than the `fields`).

The method's return value can be `Optional<CandleEntity>`.