# Get lastest document in Mongo Repository

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data

I have the following `Model`

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Document(collection = "Datalog")
public class Logger {

    @Transient
    public static final String SEQUENCE_NAME = "customer_sequence";

    @Id
    private int id;
    @NotBlank
    private String date;
    @NotBlank
    private String status;

    public MoengageImportLog(String currentDate, String status) {
        this.date = currentDate;
        this.status = status;
    }
}
```

Where `id` is an integer autogenerated by `dbsequence`

```
@Document(collection = "DataSequence")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class DbSequence {
    @Id
    private String  id;
    private int seq;
}
```

I would like to write a method to receive the last inserted element in the database, I tried this:

```
@Repository
public interface LoggerDAO extends MongoRepository<Logger, Integer> {

    Logger findTop1ById();
}
```

But got the `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0` error.

What should the correct method be in my case?

Comment: `MongoRepository<Logger, String>{...` The second parameter represents the `id` field type, which is of Integer type.

Comment: Yep, my bad. I edited my post.

Comment: In case the max value of a field of all documents fulfills your need, try using this approach: [Spring Repository, create manual covered query for max value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68092335/spring-repository-create-manual-covered-query-for-max-value/68101274#68101274).

Comment: I still got the error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot set property map because no setter, no wither and it's not part of the persistence constructor public org.json.JSONObject()!

I tried adding the `@Query` annotation and changed the method name to `findTopByOrderByIdDesc`

Comment: Maybe you need to include get/set methods in the corresponding POJO class.